# Problems to connect to my DB with the Bottle-Peewee-Plugin

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle, peewee

I have made a script (**dbcreation.py**) which creates a database with the [bottle-peewee-plugin](https://github.com/klen/bottle-peewee):

```
import os, sys
from bottle import Bottle
from bottle_peewee import PeeweePlugin
from peewee import Model, ForeignKeyField, CharField, TextField, IntegerField, BooleanField, DateTimeField, DateField, TimeField
import datetime

app = Bottle()
db = PeeweePlugin('sqlite:///x.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db.proxy

class Roomtype(BaseModel):
        roomtype_de = CharField(max_length=80)
        hint_de = CharField(max_length=250)

app.install(db)

db.database.create_tables([Roomtype])

roomtypes = [
    {'roomtype_de': 'bla'},
    {'roomtype_de': 'bla'},
]

with db.database.atomic():
    Roomtype.insert_many(roomtypes).execute()
```

and another script (**app.py**) which will contain my bootle-app:

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, get, post, request, run, template
from bottle_peewee import PeeweePlugin
from peewee import Model, ForeignKeyField, CharField, TextField, IntegerField, BooleanField, DateTimeField, DateField, TimeField    

app = Bottle()
db = PeeweePlugin('sqlite:///x.db')

@route('/my_function')
def my_function():
        return db.database.Roomtype.get(Roomtype.id == 1).roomtype_de

app.install(db)
```

I can't select any entries in my db and receive following traceback:

```
return db.database.Roomtype.get(Roomtype.id == 1).roomtype_de
AttributeError: 'SqliteDatabase' object has no attribute 'Roomtype'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change it to:

```
db.Roomtype.get(...)
```

I'm confused why you're using `db.Roomtype` in some places and just plain old `Roomtype` elsewhere, though.

Comment: Where do you mean? db.Roomtype.get(Roomtype.id == 1).roomtype_de
AttributeError: 'PeeweePlugin' object has no attribute 'Roomtype' - Could it be that the class definitions should stay in the same file as my app in order to access it?

Comment: Solved: 'def my_function():
 return Roomtype.get(Roomtype.id == 3).roomtype_de' works, if the classes are within the same file.